# How to send SMS message from Wordpress, using Twilio?

Tags: php, wordpress, twilio

I'm trying to use Twilio in a Wordpress app and it didn't work, but my same code works in a different site/server.

I added the [twilio-php](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php) folder and some PHP code to call it inside the wordpress root. I also added code to include it in the existing Wordpress PHP code, and I can't figure it out where the problem is. Can you help?

```
<?php              

                require "twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php";
               /* Send an SMS using Twilio. You can run this file 3 different ways:
                *
                * - Save it as sendnotifications.php and at the command line, run 
                *        php sendnotifications.php
                *
                * - Upload it to a web host and load mywebhost.com/sendnotifications.php 
                *   in a web browser.
                * - Download a local server like WAMP, MAMP or XAMPP. Point the web root 
                *   directory to the folder containing this file, and load 
                *   localhost:8888/sendnotifications.php in a web browser.
                */
                // Include the PHP Twilio library. You need to download the library from 
                // twilio.com/docs/libraries, and move it into the folder containing this 
                // file.


                // Set our AccountSid and AuthToken from twilio.com/user/account
                $AccountSid = "********************";
                $AuthToken = "*********************";

               // Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
               $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

               /* Your Twilio Number or Outgoing Caller ID */
               $from = '**********';

               // make an associative array of server admins. Feel free to change/add your 
               // own phone number and name here.
               $people = array(
                "*********" => "******",
                "**********" => "*********",


               );

              // Iterate over all admins in the $people array. $to is the phone number, 
              // $name is the user's name
              foreach ($people as $to => $name) {
                 // Send a new outgoing SMS */
                 $body = "Hello this is a test message";
                 $client->account->sms_messages->create($from, $to, $body);
                 echo "Sent message to $name";
              }

?>
```

Comment: at least if you know give me a a liknk.............

Comment: Hey! Sorry to hear you're having trouble getting started. Two things that would be helpful. 1) When you run this script in your browser, what (if any) is the output on the screen? 2) Do you have access to error logs on your server? If so can you paste the results here? They will help debug the problem.

Comment: actuly no thing out puts in the display...,i ll checke errorlogs in the sever ...,thank you....

Comment: thanks Kevin Burke for your answer..,yap i check the server log and notice that curel is not installed in the server  then i installed is and reboot the server and now it works fine thank you for your great support... thanx :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i check the server log and notice that curel is not installed in the server then i installed  and reboot the server and now it works fine thank you for your great support...Kevin Burke thanx :D